# How to get only text in Custom Material Spinner with Image and Text

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a Material Spinner which displays an image and text, but i want to retrieve just the text in OnItemSelected. But it is returning null.

My Adapter Class

```
   public class SpinnerCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int cat_pics[];
    ArrayList<String> categoryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public SpinnerCustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] cat_pics, ArrayList<String> categoryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.cat_pics = cat_pics;
        this.categoryNames = categoryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cat_pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon.setImageResource(cat_pics[i]);
        names.setText(categoryNames.get(i));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Setting the Adapter in Main Activity

```
 customAdapter=newSpinnerCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cat_pics,allCatNames);
    spCategories.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    spCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

onItemSelected

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Item : " + customAdapter.getItem(position) ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SpinnerCustomAdapter`, your `getItem()` method returns `null`

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}
```

**Update `getItem()` method as below:**

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return categoryNames.get(i);
}
```

**#.** You can also use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` to get get selected `item`.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Item : " 
                   + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: it works. it had not changed the return value at getItem(). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

(Or)
Inside OnItemSelectedListener:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.d("SeletedItem",adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried both, and they both are still returning "null"

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, may help you

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String text = spinner.getItemAtPosition(i)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected : " text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```